# Open balls in a subset versus the ambient set

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, proof-explanation

I think there is a subtlety in the proof of the below statement that I don't fully understand. The statement of the proposition is straightforward.

> Let $U_i$ for $i \in I$ be open in the metric space $X$. Then $U = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} U_i$ is open.

The proof I had in mind is:

> Let $x \in U$. Then there exists $i_0 \in I$ such that $x \in U_{i_0}$. As $U_{i_0}$ is open, there exists $r > 0$ such that $B_r (x) \subset U_{i_0} \subset U$.

The problem with this proof is that $B_r (x)$ is not an open ball in $U$, but an open ball with respect to $U_{i_0}$. (I don't know if I'm using the correct phraseology, so someone please correct me. Should I say "with respect to the topology of $U_{i_0}$? I believe this is just the "inherited" topology or the topology of the metric induced by $X$ on $U_{i_0}$.) If I wanted to be pedantic about notation, I can write:
\begin{align*} 
B_r^{U_{i_0}}(x) & = \{q \in U_{i_0} \mid d(x,q) < r\} \\ 
B_r^{U} (x) & = \{q \in U \mid d(x,q) < r\}. 
\end{align*}
These are not the same sets unless $(U \setminus U_{i_0}) \cap B_r^{U} (x) = \emptyset$. I'm not fully sure how, however, to reconcile this in my proof above. The open ball in $U_{i_0}$ doesn't extend beyond $U_{i_0}$. If I extend it to $U$, it. might, but that isn't a problem because then it will still remain in $U$. I'm not fully comfortable with just adding a line saying, "then, regarding this as an open ball in $U$, $B_r (x) \subset U$" because I don't fully understand the jump.

Can someone help me reconcile these steps?

Comment: Topologies on metric spaces are induced by the metric. Subspaces inherit the metric so there is no problem.

Comment: $B_r(x)$ here means the set of all $y \in X$ with $d(x, y) < r$. Those are the balls we take into account when we assert that $U_i$ is open in $X$.

Comment: A set $O$ is open iff $\forall x \in O: \exists r>0: B_r(x)=\{y \in X\mid d(x,y)< r\} \subseteq O$; there is no "ball in  a subset" notion to consider at all.

Comment: So in other words, the original proof I wrote down with the shortcut $B_r (x) \subset U_{i_0} \subset U$ is ok, because the open ball $B_r (x)$ already considered $q \in X$? If this, makes perfect sense. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, it's completely fine.

Comment: In fact keep your idea in mind when you start on subspace topologies. If $A \subseteq (X,d)$ we can trivially construct a metric space $(A,d_A)$ by defining $d: A \times A \to \Bbb R$ by $d_A = d\restriction_{A \times A}$. Then a ball in $A$ using $d_A$ is related by intersection to the ball in $X$ by $$B_{d_A}(a,r)= B_d(a,r) \cap A$$ for all $a \in A$. This gives rise to the notion of a subspace topology.